# Rectangle Project Error Fixing

Tags: java, object

I am currently working on a project called Rectangle project in which I am supposed to do the following on Java:

Make the following methods:

- setOrigin
- area
- move

Also make a method that determines if two rectangles intersect and returns a new intersection Rectangle. Test all your methods in the ObjectDemo program for the following rectangles:

- A: Origin 0,0: width 10: height 20
- B: Origin 5,5: width 15, height 15
- C: Origin 20,12: width 10: height 20
  What is the area of each? Test if each of them intersect with the other two and what is the intersection area. Move A by 5,5; B by -5,-5: and C by -20, 0. Now give the intersection area of each.

I need to finish this by Monday but I keep getting a ton of errors like unrecognized variables, etc., and I'm not sure how to fix them. Please let me know!

I have three files: Point, RectangleTest, and Rectangle.

Here are their codes:

Point code:

```
public class Point
{

//Class variables
private int xCoord; //Private (instead of Public) because we are going to use this class in the other file
                       //We don't want people changing the values unless we let them 
private int yCoord; //Variables are not in a function so will maintain their value

//Constructor
Point()
{
    xCoord = 0;
    yCoord = 0;
}

//Constructor
Point(int startX, int startY) 
{
    xCoord = startX;
    yCoord = startY;

}

public int getX()
{
    return xCoord;
}
public int getY()
{
    return yCoord;
}       

public void setX(int newX)
{
    xCoord = newX;  
}

public void setY(int newY)
{
    yCoord = newY;  
}

public void move(int moveX, int moveY)
{
    xCoord+=moveX;
    yCoord+=moveY;
}

Point(Point p) 
{
    xCoord = p.getX();
    yCoord = p.getY();
}
}
```

RectangleTest Code:

```
public class RectangleTest
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{

    Rectangle A = new Rectangle(0,0,10,20);
    Rectangle B = new Rectangle(5,5,15,15);
    Rectangle C = new Rectangle(20,12,10,20);   

    //Move rectangles
    A.moveby(5,10);
    B.moveby(-5,-5);
    C.moveby(-20,0);

    int areaA = A.getarea;
    System.out.println("The area of rectangle A is " +areaA);

    int areaB = B.getarea;
    System.out.println("The area of rectangle B is " +areaB);

    int areaC = C.getarea;
    System.out.println("The area of rectangle C is " +areaC);

    Rectanlge iAB = A.intersect(B);
    Rectangle iAC = A.intersect(C);
    Rectangle iBC = B.intersect(C);

    if(iab != null)
    {
        System.out.println("The area of intersection rectangle iab = " +iAB.area());
    }

    if(iac != null)
    {
        System.out.println("The area of intersection rectangle iac = " +iAC.area());
    }

    if (ibc != null)
    {
        System.out.println("The area of intersection area ibc = " +iBC.area());
    }   
}
}
```

Rectangle Code:

```
public class Rectangle
{
Point origin;
int height;
int width;

//Constructor for rectangle object
Public Rectangle(int startX, int startY, int startW, int startH)
{
    origin = new Point (startX, startY);
    width = startW;
    height = startH;
}

//Set origin point for NEW rectangle origins
//FIX 
public void setOrigin(int newX, int newY)
{
    origin.setX(newX);
    origin.setY(newY);
}

public int moveBy(int moveX, int moveY)
{
    origin.move(moveX, moveY);
}

public int getArea()
{
    int recArea = height*width;
    return recArea;
}

public Rectangle intersect(Rectangle testR)
{
    int meTRX = origin.getX() + width;
    int meTRY = origin.getY() + height;
    int testTRX = testR.origin.getX() + width;
    int testTRY = testR.origin.getY() + height;

    //Boolean to get iTRX
    if(meTRX>testTRX)
    {
        int iTRX = testTRX;
    }

    else 
    {
        int iTRX = meTRX;
    }

    //Boolean to get iTRY
    if(meTRY>testTRY)
    {
        int iTRY = testTRY;
    }

    else
    {
        int iTRY = meTRY;
    }

    //Boolean to get iBLX
    if(testBLX>meBLX)
    {
        int iBLX = testBLX;
    }

    else
    {
        int iBLX = meBLX;
    }

    //Boolean to get iBLY
    if(testBLY>meBLY)
    {
        int iBLY = testBLY;
    }

    else
    {
        int iBLY = meBLY;
    }

    //Testing for whether or not there is an intersection rectangle
    if(iTRX-iBLX<0 || iTRY-iBLY<0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    int iH = iTRY - iBLY;
    int iW = iTRX - iBLX;

    int intersectArea = iH * iW;

}
}
```

Please point out any problems! I'm rather new to programming, so I usually make a lot of simple mistakes. Also, I would appreciate if there are no newly introduced commands or anything because my teacher is pretty strict about doing it this way.

Thanks!

P.S. I would appreciate any extra knowledge or info on code improvement (just in general). Thanks!

Comment: Please narrow the scope of your question; for example, specific errors.

Comment: Mostly it's unrecognized variables. Such as "cannot find variable testBLX,etc."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of Issues:

- Java is case sensitive so Public is not same as public in your rectangle class.
- When your method doesnt return anything you should use void as return type. So in your method `public int moveBy(int moveX, int moveY)`, you should change it to `public void moveBy(int moveX, int moveY)`
- You need to define variables before using them. So variables like testBLX, meBLX, testBLY, meBLY, iTRX, iTRY, iBLX, iBLY are undefined. I am not sure from where the values will get populated. But you could avoid the compilation error by defining them as `int testBLX = 0;` and similarly the others.

Comment: Oh, I see. So because testBLX and meBLX are the origin points of each rectangle, would that mean that I would have to set them to be origin points?

Comment: Yes then initialize them with 0 as origin co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Rectangle` class:

- In the constructor your wrote `Public Rectangle(int startX, int startY, int startW, int startH)`, but you actually want `public Rectangle(int startX, int startY, int startW, int startH)`. In Java keywords start always with a lower case.
- Your method for changing the origin of a rectangle `public int moveBy(int moveX, int moveY)` has `int` as a return type, so the compiler wants you to return an integer value. I suppose you did not want to return anything at all so you can change the return type to `void`.
- In your intersect method `public Rectangle intersect(Rectangle testR)` you declare your variables (iTRX, iTRY, iBLX, iBLY) such as `int iTRX = testTRX;` only in the scope of your if/else statements which means that after every if/else statement these variables are not available anymore. To learn more about the different scopes of variables: [Variable scopes](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

In your `RectangleTest` class:

- You forgot a part of your task:

  > What is the area of each? Test if each of them intersect with the other two and what is the intersection area.

Some general leads:

- The use of more descriptive variable names improves the readability. For example the variable name *meTRX* does not have any meaning for me as person who did not work on your code or maybe for you if you review your code two months later.
- Before you start coding, you could check if Java has built-in classes which you can use. In your case Java provides a `Point` class in the package `java.awt.Point`. You do not have to reinvent the wheel.
- I would also recommend to read the Java Code Conventions [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) which can bring you and others who read your code on a common denominator in the future.